# jQuery validation validates disabled input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have set up validation for my form using jQuery validation.  The unfortunate thing is that at some points I want to call `$("#clientConfigurationForm").valid()` to force re-evaluation when a user enables / disables a check box.  I want input forms that are currently invalid to be ignored (and lose the validation state) when they are disabled and `.valid()` is called.  Currently this isnt happening.  How can I get this to work?

**Checkbox events**

```
$("#clientConfigurationForm").on("change","input[type=checkbox]",function(){
    $(this)
        .closest("div")
        .find("input, select")
        .not(this)
        .not(":submit")
        .prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"))
        .each(function(){
            $(this).valid();
        });
});
```

**Validation Code**

```
$("#clientConfigurationForm").validate({
    onkeyup: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    focusInvalid: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
            return;

        // Find out what my ID is
        var formIndex = $(validator.errorList[0].element).prop("id").replace(/[A-Za-z]+/g, '');
        $("#clientSettingsLinks a").eq(formIndex).trigger("click");
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var parent = $(element).parent();
        var validationContainer = parent.find(".validationResult");

        if (validationContainer.length == 0){
            validationContainer = $('<span class="validationResult"><i class="'+errorIconClass+' inputValidationIcon"></i></span>');
            parent.append(validationContainer);
        }

        validationContainer.addClass("tooltip").attr("title", error.text());
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parent().find("i").removeClass("icon-ok").addClass(errorIconClass);

        $(element).addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parent().find("i").removeClass(errorIconClass).addClass("icon-ok");
        $(element).parent().find("span.validationResult.tooltip").removeClass("tooltip").attr("title", "");

        $(element).removeClass("error");
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("SUBMITTED YO");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SjH4A/

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for responding, please check out the update http://jsfiddle.net/SjH4A/1/ - if you notice that if you make the validation fail in the input box then tick the checkbox to disable it, the validation isnt removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation:](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) *Inputs of type submit and reset are always ignored, so are disabled elements.*

However it seems you have found something weird.

This works

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SjH4A/)

```
var val;
$("#clientConfigurationForm").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
    val.resetForm();
    $(this)
        .closest("div")
        .find("input, select")
        .not(this)
        .not(":submit")
        .prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"))
        .not(":disabled")  
        .each(function () {
          $(this).valid();
        });
});

val = $("#clientConfigurationForm").validate({

    onkeyup: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    focusInvalid: false,
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert("submitted");
    }
});
```

Comment: If I remove all validation customisation it still has the same issue

Comment: See the first code block on my question, yes I do! It is odd indeed as I thought this was standard behaviour :/ `.prop("disabled", !$(this).prop("checked"))`

Comment: Ah that works! There is one niggling issue, the error icon (my custom placed one) doesnt get removed even though the input box gets its `error` class removed

Comment: can you call val.unhighlight() ?

Comment: I literally just did this in the checked handler function `$("#clientConfigurationForm .validationResult").remove();`